# From Ember Pre1 to Pre4: Multiple dynamic segments per route? Update: What is the allowed syntax for dynamic segments?

Tags: ember.js

I am currently trying to migrate my Ember based on pre1 to the current release pre4. In my pre1-code, i defined a route as follows:

```
formCreated : Ember.Route.extend({
        route : '/genre=:genre/sorting=:sorting/location=:location/range=:range/time=:date/:timeFrame',
....
})
```

This Route worked fine for me, but now i am struggling to mimic this behaviour with pre4. This is my approach:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("/");
  this.route("formCreated", { path: "/genre=:genre/sorting=:sorting/location=:location/range=:range/time=:date/:timeFrame" });
});
App.FormCreatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(context, params){
    // here i am returning a hash containing all the dynamic segments
  }
});
```

**What is going wrong?**
When the App enters the state, the URL does not get updated properly. I am seeing this result:

> */genre=:genre/sorting=:sorting/location=:location/range=:range/time=:date/6:00-19:00*

So most of my dynamic segments do not get updated. I made sure that my custom serialize method is returning an appropriate hash object, where one property for each dynamic segment is set.

**Are multiple dynamic segments per route still possible with pre4 or do i have to switch to some route nesting approach or something like that?**

**UPDATE: Root cause found:**
I just discovered that the error happened because of the syntax i used for the route. I changed it to the following(replaced the "=" with "/"):

```
this.route("formCreated", { path: "/genre/:genre/sorting/:sorting/location/:location/range/:range/time/:date/:timeFrame" });
```

**Is there any documentation on how the path may be structured?** It seems that syntax has changed since ember-pre1. I would like to have a user friendly URL and those numerous Slashes make it difficult to read. Or is the rule, that a segment always has to start with ":/"?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use resource nesting, like described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) and [here](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('/');
    this.resource('genre', { path: '/genre/:genre_id' }, function(params) {
        this.resource('sorting', { path: '/sorting/:sorting_id' }, function(params) {
            ...
        });
     });
});
```