# How do I handle form submission in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a form with various controls. When the submit button is pushed an ajax request is sent to the server which answers with some json data I want to display properly. This is a one-off thing, no bindings, etc needed, the data is read-once and discarded afterwards. I can think of some ways to do this combining views and jquery but what is the **proper** way to do this in Ember.js?

More specifically:

1) How do I communicate the form parameters from the view to the controller that is going to handle the submission event?

2) If I were to create a route to represent the submitted form state how do I serialize the parameters into a route path that makes sense for Ember? Is that even possible?

Comment: Regarding number 2, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164461/how-do-you-maintain-the-page-state-so-that-you-can-provide-permalinks-using-emb/18249404#18249404

Comment: Have you already had a look at ember-data https://github.com/emberjs/data ?

Comment: @matteo I am not currently using ember-data. I am learning ember and I want to first understand how the magic works before delving deeper. The above question actually crystallizes a lot of my confusion regarding what could be done versus what should be done in Ember.

Comment: @mavilein Great, thanks, I think that clears 2)

Comment: If anyone is interesting, we created a new project for Ember that helps building forms styled with Bootstrap easily. Github: http://github.com/ember-addons/ember-forms Demo page: http://ember-addons.github.io/ember-forms

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since no one answered yet, i have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/2VfJK/1/) showing how i would to this.

This is the basic approach:

1. I would setup a controller with a fresh (== empty) model.
2. Use **bindings** to synchronize the values of form elements to the model of the controller.
3. Create a action that takes the updated model and does whatever you want with it (**this replaces the traditional form submit**).

**So the approach is fundamentally different from the traditional way of handling forms this way:**

1. There is **no HTML form element**, since it is not needed.
2. The data is not submitted automatically to the server, instead you would  **send/submit it manually via javascript logic**. Imho this is an advantage as you could perform additional logic before or after submitting the data to the server.
3. This **plays nicely with REST-API approaches** like ember-date or ember-epf :-)

The example shows a form (just conceptually, as there is no HTML form element) to enter a first and last name. The entered values are synced to the model and you can can "perform a submit".

**The JS code:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName : "",
    lastName : ""
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return App.Person.create()
  },
    setupController : function(controller, model){
        controller.set("model", model);
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    submitAction : function(){
        // here you could perform your actions like persisting to the server or so
        alert("now we can submit the model:" + this.get("model"));
    }
});
```

**The template showing the use of value bindings:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Index Content:</h2>
  {{input valueBinding="model.firstName"}}
  {{input valueBinding="model.lastName"}}
    <button {{action submitAction target="controller"}}>Pseudo Submit</button>
  <p>{{model.firstName}} - {{model.lastName}}</p>
</script>
```

Comment: I would argue that a form element is needed to support people submitting with methods other than hitting the button, such as pressing the "return" key.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's just not absolutely needed, but it is still handy, as you pointed out correctly.

Comment: A form element is still required for accessibility see [1], for example for screen readers. What i usually do is to put a `{{action "dummy" on="submit"}}` in the `<form>` tag whose action does nothing if I want to prevent the default behavior.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Comment: This is a good way to handle forms, but it introduce one problem: when you leave the route in your store you have one record which is not persisted on backend. So, if you switch between this route and another each time you enter the current route you will add new record to the store. To workaround that problem create a `deactivate` hook on `IndexRoute` which will be called on leaving current route with follow code `var model = this.modelFor("index");

    if (model.get("isNew")) {
      this.store.deleteRecord(model);
    }
`. This will delete not saved record from the store.