# How to get text box value in ember.js

Tags: textbox, ember.js

i have started to work on ember.js just day before.
i don't know how to get text box value while submitting. i have tried like this

this is html

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div >
     <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="fname"}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lname"}}</p>
    </div>
    <button {{action save}}>submit</button>
    </script>
```

this is my ember.js file

```
          App = Ember.Application.create();
          App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

           save:function()
           {
              var fname=this.get('fname');
              var lname=this.get('lname');
              alert(fname+','+lname);


           }
          });
```

whenever i am clicking on submit button, i am getting undefined in alert.so how to get value? i hope anyone will help me for to continue in ember.js

Comment: I answered a very very similar question yesterday. Maybe you could have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js/18323040#18323040

Answer (score 10):

in js like this

```
App.WebFormController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    fname: null,
    lname: null,
    save: function () {
        var fname = this.get('fname');
        var lname = this.get('lname');
        alert(fname + ',' + lname);
    }
});
```

**without need a model**

in template  like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="web_form">
    <form {{action save on="submit"}}>
        <div >
            <p>{{input type="text" valueBinding="fname"}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>{{input type="text" valueBinding="lname"}}</p>
        </div>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. For those coming across this question now, newer versions of Ember (at least as of v 1.10+) use 'value' instead of 'valueBinding'. Like so: `{{input type="text" value=fname}}` (notice lack of quotes around fname).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your form doesn't have a model. You can provide it using `model` or `setupController` hook.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {};
  },
  // or
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('model', {});
  }
});
```

In addition some tips:

Use the `action name on="submit"` in the form, instead of `action name` in submit button. So you can execute the action when the user press enter key, in input.

And the `input type="text"` helper is a shortcut for `view Ember.TextField`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <form {{action save on="submit"}}>
        <div >
            <p>{{input type="text" valueBinding="fname"}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>{{input type="text" valueBinding="lname"}}</p>
        </div>
        <button>submit</button>
    <form>
</script>
```

[Here a live demo](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/737/edit)

Answer (score 2):

That is really nice tutorial by **mavilein.**

We can do it at controller level also.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        content:function(){
           return {fname:null,lname:null}
           }.property(),
       save:function()
       {
          var fname=this.get('fname');
          var lname=this.get('lname');
          alert(fname+','+lname);


       }
});
```

Or we can do it

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
       fname:null,
       lname:null,
       save:function()
       {
          var fname=this.get('fname');
          var lname=this.get('lname');
          alert(fname+','+lname);


       }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me:

**cshtml:** In script on tag  specify   data-template-name="text"

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="text">
   {{view Ember.TextField value=view.message}}
   {{view Ember.TextField value=view.specy}}
   {{textarea value=view.desc id="catdesc" valueBinding="categor" cols="20" rows="6"}}

   <button type="submit" {{action "submit" target=view}}>Done</button>
   </script>
```

**app.js:**

```
App.TextView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'text',
message:'',
specy: '',
desc:'',
actions: {
    submit: function (event) {
        var value = this.get('specy');
        var spc = this.get('message');
        var de = this.get('desc');
    }
}
});
```