# How to get input from emberjs forms and pass it to rails controller backend for actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, actionmailer

I am trying to use actionmailer to send out email notification to myself whenever a user submits his/her suggestions to me at my site utilizing a form.

I am currently using emberjs for my front-end and rails as my back-end.

With that, the user will input the following fields into the emberjs form:

- Name
- Email
- Message

May I know how can I capture the input from emberjs (via controller) and pass it to my rails controller for actionmailer usage to fire an notification email to me with the name, email add, and message to my email whenever any users send a suggestion to me? I am not using any model at all in this case, as I intend it to be a pass through only.

Suggestions or advices are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at my answer in another question, how you should basically go about form handling in EmberJS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js/18323040#18323040

Comment: If you understood this answer, you can have a look at https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm for a more convenient way of defining forms.

Comment: @mavilein, that means I would need to do the following:

1. Create a model for EmberJS to manage this
2. Utilize valueBinding to bind the form input to the model
3. Add action to submission to GET the input value and pass to the controller
4. Pass input of EmberJS controller to rails controller and do as per how actionmailer is usually done in the rails controller

With that, 
- Is my understanding correct?
- Could you show a simple example how data from emberJS controller can be passed to rails controller?

Thanks! Appreciate for time!

Comment: For the EmberJS part you are correct. I am no rails developert so i cannot help you on this part :-). Can't you just use plain jQuery $.ajax ?

Comment: that is fine @mavilein =) I am not sure about that as I still got a lot more to learn in terms of having both emberJS and Rails interact!! =)