# Run function when input is submitted

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking to take a simple input & run it's value through a function, and display the result of that function in another place in the same template. I just cannot figure out where I connect the binding to show the result of the function. I'm trying to run a calculation on the value entered and push the result to `{{suggestedGrams}}`. I'm using the generated view for this template.

Here's what I've got:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="brew">
{{input type="text" id="start-brew" placeholder="Enter a number, e.g: 16" name=id value=submittedOunces action="startBrew"}}

<p>We recommend using {{suggestedGrams}} grams of coffee for {{ounces}} oz. in a {{id}}.</p>
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
App.BrewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
submittedOunces: "",
// updates the {{ounces}} binding with value typed in input
ounces: function() {
     if (this.submittedOunces.length < 1) {
        return "";
     } else {
        return this.get("submittedOunces");
     }
}.property("submittedOunces"),
    actions: {
        startBrew: function () {
           // other logic is here to show hidden div's
        }
    }
});
```

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I'm completely new to Ember so it's hard to search for the right terms to find what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To get an answer please read this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If you add `suggestedGrams: "test"` to your controller, does that show up? Are you trying to caclulate `suggestedGrams` somewhere?

Comment: @claptimes - yes. Sorry if my description isn't clear. I took out some code just for brevity. Essentially I want to take the value entered into the input and run some math against it (something like "value entered" * 2, for example).

Comment: Why can't you do the same type of function you did for `ounces` but for `suggestedGrams`?

Comment: Duh. I tried that previously, but I was facing issues with scope & setting the correct values from one function & trying to access them in another function. Thanks for the heads up to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this thanks to @claptimes (see comments to original question) by adding another function. The hurdle I was having trouble with was with function scope - I was reading a variable in one function and for some reason I was expecting that to be available in another function. Here's my final code:

```
App.BrewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    submittedOunces: "",
    ounces: function() {
         if (this.submittedOunces.length < 1) {
            return "";
         } else {
            return this.get("submittedOunces");
         }
    }.property("submittedOunces"),
    // This is where I was running into trouble.
    // I needed to declare the value again to gain access to it.
    grams: function() {
        var submittedOunces = this.get("submittedOunces");
        return submittedOunces * 2; // or whatever the function (in my case, a simple math formula) needs to be
    }.property("submittedOunces"),
    actions: {
        startBrew: function () {    
            $('.hide').fadeIn("fast");      
        }
    }
});
```