# rendering data from ajax request not made in model function

Tags: ember.js

I'm making a simple application where I am making the same ajax call over and over again (with setInterval), and it's triggered not by the user moving into a route, but rather by clicking a button that triggers setInterval to start.  Therefore, I'm not fetching data with the `model` hook that is triggered by moving into a route, since that hook is only called once, and then the template is rendered automatically. Rather, I have an `jsonRequest` function in a controller that is called by the startInterval function over and over again. Therefore, there is no automatic rendering of the data in the template in the way that happens with the `model` hook. So once my data is returned after each ajax request, I wish to append it to a list, or somehow add it to the index.html, but I can't find a way to do this with Ember's api. How do I add data to index.html (I don't want to call it the `view` because I haven't yet created a `view`) after the request returns?

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

      jsonRequest: function(){
        var datasource = 'http://localhost:8080';
        return new Ember.$.ajax({url: App.Index.url, dataType: "json", type: 'GET'}).then(function(data){  
              console.log(data)     

        })
      },
     startInterval: function(){
          console.log("startInterval");
         App.Index.setIntervalId = setInterval( this.jsonRequest, (1000));
     }


   App.Index = Ember.Object.extend({
    url: "",
    setIntervalId: "",

  });

   App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

     model: function(){
       return App.Index.create();
   },
```

There's a jsbin here showing the error that gets thrown when I try to add the data from the ajax call to the objects property on the index controller (as suggested by SO user Buck).  The bin doesn't show attempt to loop through `objects` in the template, because we never get that far http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bomilowiha/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the data you received into an `Ember.Object` and add it to a controller property.

Sample controller code:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  objects: [],
  jsonRequest: function() {
     Ember.$.ajax({/* your request */}).then(function(data) {
       var object = /* code to turn the data into an object for display */;
       this.get('objects').pushObject(object);
     }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Then in your template, you can just iterate over the model array:

```
{{#each object in objects}}
  display object properties here
{{/each}}
```

The specifics of how to turn the JSON into an object for display, and how to display the object, are dependent on your needs.

Comment: The problem here is that I am not accumulating the objects and then rendering them all at once (say, by iterating over a loop of objects). Rather, once each object is returned, I wish to render it, and then do the same with the next object, so making the model array doesn't seem right. Did I misunderstand your answer? or can you suggest something different?

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, I had already created the model when I moved into the route ` App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(){
      return App.Index.create();
    },` and that model isn't an array, but rather is the App.Index you see at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: If you add a new object to the array, it will be rendered automatically. Does the model have any functionality? The code you put in the post for the model doesn’t seem to do anything.

Comment: I use that model in a form to collect data `
  {{input valueBinding="model.url" placeholder="blah"}}
    <button {{action 'submitAction' target="controller"}}>Submit</button>`. That way, when the form is submitted, I can set the url for the ajax request because the url from the form is attached to the model

Comment: this was the logic I followed in creating the model that way (i.e. to help with form submission), which makes it impossible? to declare the model as you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js

Comment: Okay, it doesn’t have to be the controller’s model. You can call it `objects` (or hopefully a more domain-specific name) and refer to it in the template that way. You can add any number of properties to a controller for use in the template.

Comment: I added the `objects` property in the controller along with this `this.get('objects').pushObject(object);` inside the jsonRequest and it says, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` each time it tries to get and push the object into the array

Comment: error duplicated here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bomilowiha/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: I accepted your answer but it actually need another small change to get it to work `this.jsonRequest.bind(this)` and then inside the jsonRequest I did `var that = this` and made the get call with `that.get('objects')`....appreciate your help

Comment: Ah yes, as I was typing I thought “I should remember to bind `this`” and forgot by the end of the function haha