# adding second model to route makes first undefined

Tags: ember.js

In my current Ember setup, I retrieve a store for the Index Route. This works fine.

```
 App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(){      
          var store = this.store.find('index');        
          return store;
        }

  });
```

However, I wish to create a custom form object for the same route, and therefore following the advice of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route)tried to return two models for the Index Route like this, however, I now get the error

```
Error while processing route: index that is not defined ReferenceError: that is not defined
```

New Code

```
  App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(){      

          return Ember.RSVP.hash({
           store: this.store.find('index'),
           customform: App.CustomForm.create()
          });
       }


  });
```

How can I add a second model to this route?

Update
The index model had a date property that I was using to sort the items in the index model

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        sortProperties: ['date'],
        sortAscending: false,
```

I was originally displaying the index model with this in the html

```
    {{#each item in arrangedContent}}
 <li> {{some-component id=item.customid date=item.date data=item.junk}} </li>

    {{/each}}
```

By adding the second model, whether or not i use the store to create a record, I get this error and the data from the store doesn't load in the html

```
 Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Also, I don't actually need to persist the second model I'm trying to add, so I don't desire to make it a store. In the SO answer I linked to, second models were added that weren't persisted.

Comment: why you need empty model object, if you explain your original problem may be there is a good solution already in ember js

Comment: @sushant I'm trying to create a form object that I can use in the index route following these instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js/18323040#18323040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be using the store to create your new custom form record:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){      
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            store: this.store.find('index'),
            customform: this.store.createRecord('customForm')
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not intending to persist the data, merely using the object to create a custom form as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309544/how-do-i-handle-form-submission-in-ember-js/18323040#18323040

Comment: It also doesn't get rid of the error message. I think the problem might be that I display data in the index.html {{#each item in arrangedContent}} that's expecting the old setup. Furthmore, the second model is just an ember object that I extend to create the custom form `Ember.Object.extend({`

Comment: In that case it may make sense to setup custom form on your controller: `setupController : function(controller, model){
        controller.set("customform", App.CustomForm.create());
    }` - are there any parameters you are trying to pass based on the route?

Comment: If you post the rest of your code it may help determining where the issue lays.

Comment: I added more information. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to create your customForm through your store:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      store: this.store.find('index'),
      customForm: this.store.createRecord('customForm')
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like I was too slow to the draw! Good answer, Oren ;)

Comment: Thanks, would you do this even if I'm not persisting the data?

Comment: It also doesn't get rid of the error message. I think the problem might be that I display data in the index.html `{{#each item in arrangedContent}}` that's expecting the old setup

Comment: I updated the OP to provide more information. Thank you for your assistance.