# Change URL without transition

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have a question concerning the Ember routing system.

In my Ember-App, I have a simple leaflet fullscreen map. The center and zoom level of this map are coming from the URL query parameters. Now it would be nice to have a simple way to keep this query parameters in sync with the map position. So when somebody moves the map, I would like to change the url query parameters to the new values.

When I use a simple `transitionTo`, I start a loop of changing the map and updating the query parameters changing the map again and so forth.

So my first idea was to get the location implementation from the router and changing the url manually. But I do not know how to do that. And it also feals wrong using Ember this way.

Comment: history api? I think you looking for history api.

Comment: You should not update the URL manually with the location object or something like that. The way to influence the appearance in Ember is the use of routes and add dynamic segments to them.

Comment: Have a look at the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165072/is-resource-nesting-the-only-way-to-enable-multiple-dynamic-segments/15174766#15174766
 http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/09/28/three-steps-to-ember-js-seo-friendly-urls/

Comment: And this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164461/how-do-you-maintain-the-page-state-so-that-you-can-provide-permalinks-using-emb/18249404#18249404

Those links contain all the ingredients you need. If you have problems, create a JSFiddle or JSBin and i can help you work out a basic example.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but that does not help me here. I don't want Ember to change the apps appearance. What I was looking for is a way to only change the url for having a permalink to the visible map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After many downvotes to my answer above, in Ember you could also do this so you don't go through a transition or reloading data / rendering

```
Ember.run(function(){ 
    window.history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );
});
```

Or for legacy browsers access the hash:

```
Ember.run(function(){
    location.hash = 'foo';
});
```

Comment: `window.history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );` worked well for me

Answer (score 3):

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.HistoryLocation.html#method_replaceState

Defined in packages/ember-routing/lib/location/history_location.js:134

I haven't tested this but:

```
Ember.HistoryLocation.replaceState(<string>);
```

should work.

Also my colleague recommends using the router to accomplish this:

http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/02/15/ember-1-0-rc.html#stq=&stp=0

```
router.replaceWith('index');
```

Comment: That sounds promising. Do you have an idea how to access the location? Maybe via actions in the route? I'm very new to Ember and looking for some kind of best practice.

Comment: Yeah, I have done a mistake in my code reloading the map. I now fixed it and as you stated used `router.replaceWith('index')` to change the url. Thank you!

Comment: Route replacement doesn't seem to be working for me when the new route is the same as the old route. Is that normal or am I missing something?

Comment: Either "solution" still does a complete transition, including loading data from server. I was looking for a way to change the url without going through a transition, reloading data from server, or even rerendering templates. -1.

Comment: @Gaurav you can just access the native history on window.

Comment: @Gaurav for older versions of IE access the location.hash in the url.

Comment: Tried that. Ember catches the hashchange event and triggers a full transition.

Comment: These are old questions, but note that even using `window.replaceState` won't work, because it breaks Ember's history API. Your back button won't work as expected if this happens.

Answer (score 2):

To add on previous answers, of using the straight forward approach of changing the URL when you want to change the URL, on current Ember versions there is an option of linking query parameters to controller properties.

A simple example compiled from the [Ember guide page](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/):

```
App.MapController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  queryParams: ['zoom', {latitude: 'lat'}, {longitude: 'lon'}],

  zoom: 10,
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,

  mapWindowChanged: function {
    MapApi.reposition(this.zoom, this.latitude, this.longitude);
  }.observes('zoom','latitude','longitude')
});
```

When using query params this way, controller/view code can just change the bound controller properties and query parameters will update automatically.

Use the [Ember.Route queryParams property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_queryParams) to change the way query parameters effect route events as follows:

```
App.MapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    lat: {
      refreshModel: true,
      replace: true, 
    },
    long: {
      refreshModel: true, 
      replace: true, 
    },
    zoom: {
      replace: true
    }
  }
});
```

This will tell Ember to reload needed parts from server when tilting the map, but not when changing the zoom. Also, changing parameters will not push state items to browser history.