# How to change a URL in the Ember.js router before a route is assigned?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

My Ember.js app requires backwards compatibility for links that went to specific file extensions. (i.e. .pdf)  In other words, I an example link like this, to return the PDF:

http://www.example.com/docs/my.pdf

I'm trying to preprocess the URL to remove the .pdf before the Ember.js Router assigns a Route to it, by taking a substring, and assigning it back as the URL to process:

http://www.example.com/docs/my

Obviously, getting the substring is trivial, but I don't know how to inject the updated URL back into the Ember.js Router.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is non-ember compliant from the start.  The solution isn't to update the URL, but to simply use the URL you want in the first place.

Instead of sending the user to

```
http://www.example.com/docs/my.pdf
```

Send them to

```
http://www.example.com/docs/my
```

And then within one of the related route hooks (beforeModel hook would be my preference), send the my.pdf file to the user.

Comment: This Ember.js app is replacing an old website, which has certain specific URLs which must be maintained for backwards-compatibility (per the CEO).  So I have to support the existing .pdf URL, and send it to a new location where the PDF now lives (outside the new Ember.js app).  That's why I want to eliminate the .pdf from the URL, and then just handle it in with the Router + Route, as usual.  I need to change that URL before the Router processes it.  So where would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `transitionTo()`.

Alternatively [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076834/change-url-without-transition) suggests using

```
Ember.HistoryLocation.replaceState(<string>);
```

or

```
router.replaceWith('index');
```

Comment: Where would I put that, so that it is executed before the URL is processed by the Ember.js Router and assigned a Route.  Is there a 'before hook' on the Router that allows a me to insert a function to be run to update the existing URL beforehand?

Comment: Try putting it in the `beforeModel` hook of the `App.DocsRoute`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work out. I think the URL has to be modified before the Router assigns a Route. Hoping to run across a hook that will enable me to add a preprocessor/filter before the Router handles the URL. Also open to other ideas.  Thanks!