# How can I set different data on the same model in ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my app there are two models: `App.Company` and `App.Contract`. A company has many contracts. I'm using Ember data.

I want to display all companies which have contracts that start in a given month. For example, `/Jan-2013` would show only those companies that have contracts starting in January of 2013. I would also want to display only the relevant contracts.

So, I have a `Month` resource:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('month', { path: '/:month_id' });
});
```

Each company and contract have an `id`. My question is, what's the best way to go about setting up my controllers?

Currently I'm returning only the necessary data from the server for each month. For example, April 2013 would return

```
{
    month: {
        id: "Apr-2013",
        company_ids: [5, 23, 905, 4, 59]
    },

    companies: [
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "Acme, Inc.",
            contract_ids: [94, 84, 20, 1]
        },
        ...
    ],

    contracts: [
        {
            id: 94,
            date: "2013-04-02",
            new_monthly_fee: 50182
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

If I structure things the standard way, I run into a problem. Say company at id 5 shows up in both April 2013 and May 2013. But this company also has a different array of `contract_ids` in the two months. If I first visit April, when I visit May Ember will retrieve what it thinks is the same data from the store; but it won't get the updated contracts.

I can think of two ways to solve this:

1. In the `setupController` hook in the `MonthRoute`, set the content on the `ContractsController`.
2. Remove the `id`s on both the companies and the contracts, and send them as `embedded: always` in the JSON payload.

What is the correct/idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set different data on the same model in ember data?

You cant set different data on the same model, in ember or any other MVC framework.

> What is the correct/idiomatic way to accomplish this?

When you run into this kind of issue it is a sign that you need to step back and consider modeling the domain in a different way.

When we think of an ember *model* usually that means something that exists server-side but it does not have to be that way. In this case you've got a *month* model that really does not need to exist on the server, it's just a way of representing a date range. The only server-side models are Company and Contract. So instead of querying the server for a month and sideloading company/contract data, it would be more idiomatic to query for company or contract directly, possibly including query parameters so that the server returns just the relevant contracts and their associated companies.

Now as a user moves around your app you can expect that over time most or even all of the companies and contracts are going to be in memory. In fact you might even decide to just load them all when the app boots. In any case, the query you use to restrict what gets loaded via the api is not going to have anything to do with actually *showing* the right companies via the UI. That needs to be done *client side* via a filter.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly, whichever part of the UI ends up being responsible for filtering, it would manually set the `model` on the `CompaniesController`, so that only the filtered subset is showing - right?

Comment: That's the idea. Or have a computed property on companies controller that does something like `return this.get('content').filter(....`

Comment: Also check out this SO post which explains how to specify month as a dynamic parameter to your routes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165072/is-resource-nesting-the-only-way-to-enable-multiple-dynamic-segments/15174766#15174766

Comment: The part that still confuses me is how to actually send over the filter/relationship information from the server. I wouldn't be able to use the data as structured above, correct?

Comment: It seems like might be another way to go about this. The resource here is really the month, and it has many companies, but these aren't quite the same as the companies that live on the server. They're `company-months`, and they have things that only a `company-month` would have, like a beginning monthly balance (which a `company` does not any concept of). In this case the id really becomes just another property on the `company-month`. It reminds me of a `latest-release`-type resource. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Comment: That approach could work. In that case month is like a MonthlyReport model, and really it just has a bunch of JSON data that gets displayed when you visit the month's route.

Comment: Right. If the app becomes much more complex, your model may make more sense. Thanks, you've helped clarify things.